# QSslSocket cannot resolve and Permission Denied error

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, qsslsocket

The error messages are the following:

> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb
>
> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected

I run a Windows 7 machine, with openssl 1.1.0 installed on my D: drive. And I am using Qt5.9.0

My .pro file

```
QT += core network
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    server.cpp \
    commands.cpp \
    packet.cpp

HEADERS += \
    server.h \
    commands.h \
    packet.h

INCLUDEPATH += D:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl
INCLUDEPATH += D:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin
LIBS += -L D:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib -llibcrypto
LIBS += -L D:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib -llibssl
```

And this is the code that triggers the error:

```
QString Commands::getPublicIp()
{

    QString temp;

    QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
    QUrl url("http://api.ipify.org");

    QString query = "format=json";

    url.setQuery(query);

    QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    QObject::connect(
                reply
                , &QNetworkReply::finished
                , [&](){

                        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
                            return QString();
                        } else {
                                QJsonObject jsonObject= QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
                                QHostAddress ip(jsonObject["ip"].toString());

                                temp = QString("002 " + ip.toString());
                        }

                reply->deleteLater();
                }
            );

    return temp;

}
```

I kept getting the qt.network.ssl errors, and after linking openssl I keep getting a compile error:

> :-1: error: cannot find D:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib: Permission denied
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -llibssl
>
> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Even though I am not currently using OpenSSL, I am willing to use it later.

Comment: "I am using Qt5.9.0" - I can understand using the current LTS branch of Qt (5.9) over the latest version, but you *really* want to be using the latest bug-fix version of that branch (Qt 5.9.5 at the time of writing) - there are *many* important bug fixes and performance improvements compared to 5.9.0.   Just a piece of advice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. OpenSSL 1.1.0 is only supported from Qt 5.10. Please use OpenSSL 1.0.2l, you can use the pre-built package that matches your compiler from [npcglib](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/).
2. Your `LIBS +=` includes are correct, but it appears your compute has no permission or the libraries are not found. It cannot be told why this error occurs. Verify the existence of the libraries in the folder and that your user has access.
3. `QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::get(const QNetworkRequest &request)`is an asynchron call. Your function `QString Commands::getPublicIp()` will probably return an empty QString before the request has finished.